# Windows 2008 Standard upgrade to Windows 2008 Enterprise failure

Tags: windows-server-2008

Sidestory, I was in the process of setting up a second Exchange 2010 server for DAG support, when I realized that my box needed Windows 2008 Enterprise edition. The box currently has

```
Windows 2008 Standard
Windows update including SP2
Exchange 2010 with CAS, HT, Mailbox roles
Domain Services role
File Services role.
```

When I try to upgrade to Windows 2008 Enterprise, I initially got a "your current version of windows is more recent than the intallation media", something to that effect. My first guess was it may be SP2 related, so I uninstalled SP2, restarted and tried again. This time it gave me an error to the effect

```
Windows could not configure one or more windows components. Please restart and try the update again.
```

This was at the last stage of the Windows 2008 Enterprise install when it says "Completing installation". So I removed Domain Services role (including demoting it as a DC). However I get the same error again.

Anyone see something like this before and have any suggestions? Also , is there a log file the windows upgrade program spits out that I can consult to see what component exactly is interfering?

**Update 1**
Based on some googling I finally found the setup log file, and it seems that Windows setup had an issue determining the .Net 3.0 "feature" being installed or uninstalled. So based of of a win7/vista technet article I'm going to retry the upgrade after removing the .Net 3.0 feature.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is now, but your solution would be to slipstream SP2 into the Windows 2008 enterprise build. Also, it's really not a great idea to install any Exchange roles on a DC.

Answer (score 1):

It might be to late to try it, but I did this a few weeks ago using the DISM tool. Went from Standard to Enterprise with just a few commands, no media required. It might not work with Exchange installed.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2009/10/14/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-without-media.aspx  is just one of many articles about how to do it.

Comment: As James mention using the DISM tool is the best option here. As long as you are going up in version...for example, from standard to enterprise... not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

When you got the first error, "your current version of windows is more recent than the installation media", instead of removing SP2, I would have slip-streamed an install disk for Enterprise.

I would re-install the service pack and then follow what I just suggested.

In the alternative, if you have a TechNet subscription, you can download Server 2008 with SP2 already integrated.

Comment: Well like I mentioned the setup moved along ok when I uninstalled SP2 and tried the install. however now its giving me some issues with a windows "component" configuration problem at the end of the Windows install. What component, it doesn't say. I really wish Microsoft started output-ing some specific technical information in these messages. Its going to be I.T. folks anyway who are viewing it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be just easier to run the setup program in Compatability mode as Vista SP2.

This worked for me very well.

AG